# Do windows in Firefox e10s have different process IDs?

Tags: firefox-addon, e10s

Will new windows in [Firefox e10s](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) have a common PID or different? New tabs definitely have different PIDs, I know that.

Will windows of different profiles have different PIDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stuff like this is an implementation detail, and since the implementation isn't finished yet, there is no definitive answer (and even if there was, it might change in future releases without warning).

But right now, IIRC, the following is true:

- All UI is "owned" by a single process (the main process).
- New top-level windows fully belong to the main process.
- Tabs *might* be "remote" aka. "out-of-process" (e.g. content tabs will be remote, while some other tabs will be still living in the main process, such as certain about: URIs).
- Regarding profiles: Nothing changes on that front.

You can already try this out in Nightly builds (There is a "New e10s window" menu item).

Comment: Superb didn't know that about the nightly. Will try this out. Reason I wanted to know is im trying to use ctypes to focus a window of another profile: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214335/most-recent-window-of-a-pid

Comment: By any chance do you know if it will e10 ff will have windows in multiple threads? we will of course have multiple windows in a thread right?